# Get current url inside a Script Editor

Tags: url, script, current-navigation, editor

I would like to open a New Item Form inside a Dialog. For this approach I'm using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
string SiteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url
 function displayLayover(url) {

 var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

 options.url = url;

 options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(

 null, null);

 SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
 }
 </script>
```

It works totally fine but now I would like to get the link of the current subsite, because the goal is to save the subsite as template and don't change the script manually inside the Script Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to put **url** instead **SiteUrl** it will be like this : `string url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;` however this code will not run try to use page variable **_spPageContextInfo**  : `string url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;`

> **Note :** If you use **SPContext** in **Client Object Model** code it would be
>   null.